# Python comparison functions

Tags: python, functional-programming, comparison

I have some data that lends itself to representation as a value and a comparison function, `(val, f)`, so another value can be checked against it by seeing if `f(val, another)` is `True`.  That's easy.

Some of them just need `>`, `<`, or `==` as `f`, however, and I can't find a clean way of using them; I end up writing things like `ScorePoint(60, lambda a, b: a <= b)`.  That's ugly.

Is there a way I can do something more like `ScorePoint(60, <=)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `operator` module is your friend:

```
import operator
ScorePoint(60, operator.le)
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html

Comment: Still ick --- I have to import a module just to treat operators as functions?  But that's better than doing it myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Yes:

```
 LessEqual = lambda a, b: a <= b
 ScorePoint(60, LessEqual)
```

or more concise (but less readable):

```
 LE = lambda a, b: a <= b
 ScorePoint(60, LE)
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that you don't have a 'peer pressure' badge yet ;)

Comment: I can't help but notice that people still vote down for no good reason. :-)